# Glossary or thesaurus of terms in statistics and machine learning?

Tags: discussion

Could a glossary or thesaurus of terms in statistics and machine learning,
with short examples and stats.se tags, help non-native speakers to frame questions and find answers?
In particular various areas of ML seem to me (non-expert) to have different jargons:
"the term is semi-supervised learning, not unsupervised learning".
Here a semi-supervised glossary would be useful.

(By "native speaker" I mean "fluent in statistics or ML lingo")

Answer (score 6):

Possibly, though it would have to exist here on meta.

A better solution might be to edit the tag wikis for the respective tags with explanations, assuming each term has a tag.

Comment: Definitions together would I think be handier than defs scattered around. Does anyone know of a short ML glossary / phrase book online ?  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Machine_learning -> 189 pages, including Lazy learning.)